# AWS EC2 Instace cannot connect ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, key

Someone in my company did a bit of mess and played with some permissions on the instance.
I think i managed to restore them but yes I cant connect through SSH.
I saw all the documantion - change as they suggested the permissions of my .ssh folder and the files the contacting it.
But still no succses.

This is what is see in the debug :

```
debug1: Host '[ec2-35-158-36-123.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com]:922' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: mobilePortalDev.pem (0x0), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred hostbased,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: mobilePortalDev.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:q1Dv2WPu+7ivOPemq0J1zaZdLyekni8URMGn1+zo7Aw
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I am useing only key auth.
I think is maybe locked or not writable so it just cant get to the key.

Cab some help me?

Comment: can you share what the permissions on ~/.ssh look like? your user id should be owning the folder .ssh in home folder and all the files in the folder including the folder should have 600 permissions. I am assuming that authorization keys were already present and somebody played around with permissions as mentioned by you

Answer (score 0):

Did you trying placing your public key in authorized_key file and giving it full permissions for your user

/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys